# Reference for a review in linear/multilinear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, multilinear-algebra

So, I'm in the need to review some linear algebra topics. When I took the course in my university I used Friedberg's linear algebra. I'm looking for something challenging that covers the usual linear algebra topics (from vector spaces to Jordan Canonical form) but I also need a reference for multilinear algebra (concerning quotient spaces, dual spaces, tensor product, wedge product, in particular the definition of determinant using wedge and bilinear forms).
I looked through other references but they didn't satisfy me. Thanks a lot for every comment/suggestion.

Comment: Did you look at Linear Algebra by Kenneth M Hoffman, Ray Kunze? If not, check the contents on Amazon. If I am not mistaken, all the topics you mention are there, and this is an introductory self-contained book.

Comment: seek for Werner Greub 's books